# Need to replace specific table with div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking to replace a table on a page with a div using jQuery, so I can edit them easier with CSS and use floats and responsive design. I have found the code below which successfully replaces all tables on the page with divs and spans, but I need this jQuery code to only apply these changes to one specific table and not the other tables of the page.

The specific table I would like to convert to a div is:

```
<table class="grid">
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('table').replaceWith( $('table').html()
       .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div id='table'")
       .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div")
       .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
       .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
       .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
       .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
    );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Give your table an `id`, then use the id like this: `$('#your_id').replaceWith(...);`

Comment: Would you mind showing me using the code above?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your function does what you say it does, this should be all you need.  Note that I used your name as the table ID.

```
<table class="grid" id="dan_king">
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#dan_king').replaceWith( $('#dan_king').html()
        .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div id='dan_king'")
        .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div")
        .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
        .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
        .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
        .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
     );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Marc! Too easy! :) I was actually able to hook onto the class .grid in this case. Works like a charm!